# What's the telegram API method to get "user is typing" info on a conversation?

Tags: telegram

I am trying to implement a very basic Telegram client. I would like to know how can I get the info that tells me the other user is typing.

I know how to send this information: By using the [setTyping](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.setTyping) method.

Now how can I receive it? There is no getTyping mehtod, and the API description is quite confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upon "writing status" change, your app will receive an update of the type [updateUserTyping](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/updateUserTyping). From there you can get the information.

Hope it helps