# Telegram bots - how can we detect that a user has started typing?

Tags: telegram-bot

We can get Telegram messages when they are complete and sent via long polling or webhooks, but is there a way to understand when the user has started typing?

I guess this is not a normal case for bots and I dont think there is a straight away method but could we fall back on the Telegram API for messaging apps for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the telegram API method to get "user is typing" info on a conversation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599031/whats-the-telegram-api-method-to-get-user-is-typing-info-on-a-conversation)

Comment: @Clint, base your linked page this is not a duplicate question, because it is about Telegram Bot, not Telegram Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually I found a solution in the current Bot API; [inline queries](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery). While they are not intended for this, inline queries send what the user types in to the bot in real-time, so you are alerted as soon as the first characters are typed in.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in `Telegram Core API`, named: [updateUserTyping](https://core.telegram.org/constructor/updateUserTyping).
But there is not any way in `Telegram Bot API` yet (until today: *2016-10-17*).

If you type or send a file to the bot during these processes you do not get any message from Telegram in your webhook, but it's possible they'll add a new feature to detect user typing in future Bot API updates.

Comment: For the time being I'd probably need to develop a custom messaging app for that - which defeats the purpose. Guess we have to wait for the update

Comment: @DavidNiki, Telegram Core API is more flexible now to make messaging app base telegram messaging system but Bot API has many fans, on the other hand Telegram works hard and admirable on these systems to develop them. I'm waiting for some other features in Bot API too! I think they should has clear and better ways to get feedback from developers.

Comment: as of this moment, this function does not work for bots even when you build a custom telegram client just for that. this update function is restricted  only to actual users, unfortunately